# How to align elements inside a container to each corner but keeping the correct order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styles

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get this correctly.

The situation:

I have a div (header of a card) which has an icon, a title and a span. This should be left aligned. The header can also have tags (spans) which should be right aligned (start from the right). This is easy to get using float right in the tags, the problem is that the order of the tags is wrong. I tried other things and got the order correctly, but if there are a lot of tags, and a second line is needed, it starts from the left, and it needs to start from the right.

Something like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wKcr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using something like bootstrap, so you can create your div in the specific order you want, and have it resize the divs according to screen size using the grid system.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Here is a demo using a col that disappears on small screen sizes, but appears on larger ones... (4 different sizes (col-lg-12, col-md-12, col-sm-12, col-xs-12), and you can have elements resize according to screen width).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Responsive Columns</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 576px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 ml-auto" style="background-color:lavender;">Title</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 ml-auto" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Div 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-0 ml-auto"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 ml-auto" style="background-color:lavender;">Div 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 ml-auto" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Div 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 ml-auto" style="background-color:lavender;">Div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```